# pg_query_params failing at 24464 parameters, does it have a cap? (PHP)

Tags: php, postgresql

I've built a large multi-row insert query of 10,000 rows at 8 fields, meaning I'm passing 90,000 values to pg_query_params as the data array.

I'm getting this error back:

> Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  bind message
>   supplies 24464 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 90000 in
>   class.postgresql.php on line 57

I've double checked the SQL and data array, there's definitely 90,000 values being passed but for some reason it's only detecting the magic number of 24464. Thoughts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [over the wire protocol](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/protocol-message-formats.html) used by postgres indicates that the number of parameters used is passed as a signed 2 byte integer, which 90000 obviously does not fit into.

It looks like the php driver just ignores what won't fit into the 2 byte integer - 90000 is 0x015f90, if you just take the low 2 bytes of that then you get 0x5f90 which is 24464. Break your insert into smaller batches and you should be ok

Comment: @velo9 Any chance you can submit a bug report for the pg driver in PHP? It shouldn't be ignoring parameters, it should be failing, loudly, with a clear error message.

Answer (score 4):

<clippy>It appears that you are trying to bulk-load data into your PostgreSQL database using big multi-record `INSERT` statements. This is inefficient and clumsy, though much better than using single inserts without surrounding explicit transactions. You should rewrite your code to use the [pg_copy_from()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php), making use of PostgreSQL's efficient [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) bulk-load interface via the nice interface PHP's postgresql drivers provides to it.</clippy>

In all seriousness, `COPY` is the way to go and it looks like the Pg PHP drivers support it. Seems you can also do it with [pg_put_line()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-put-line.php) and an explicit `COPY` if you need more control.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about COPY but didn't know about pg_copy_from(). However, I need to return the serialized primary key using RETURNING, which is why I was using normal INSERT. Though in my case I might be able to do all the inserts w/COPY and flag the rows to know which ones are newly inserted, then do another query to get the IDs.

Comment: Yep, that'd work. Could also have a trigger on the table you're inserting into that adds newly generated IDs to an `UNLOGGED` side-table you can `SELECT` and `TRUNCATE` to get 'em fast.

Comment: +1,000,000 for COPY!  To follow-up on Craig Ringer's comments on getting the IDs, you can do it without a trigger by (1) COPY the data into a TEMPORARY table, (2) INSERT INTO real_table (list of fields in temp table) SELECT (list of fields in temp table) FROM temp_table, and (3) JOIN between the real_table and temp_table on the non-sequential unique set of columns in the real_table to get the newly-generated sequential IDs.  After that you can either drop the temp table manually or, if it's a proper TEMPORARY table, it will get dropped on disconnect.